# Как правильно хешировать пароль Laravel? Создание пользователя через админ панель

Tags: php, laravel, хеширование

Пытаюсь создать нового пользователя через админ панель, но при создании пароля, видимо, что-то делаю не так, т.к сам пароль хешируется, но в базу данных попадает не хешированным

Я понимаю, что что-то где-то не дописал, но что и где?

Контроллер для создания нового пользователя

```
    public function store(AuthorFormRequest $request)
    {
        if($request->input('password')){
            $hash = Hash::make($request->input('password'));
        }

        User::create($request->validated());
        return redirect(route('authors'));
    }
```

Форма запросов

```
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8'],
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну Вы правильно говорите, Вы хешируете пароль, а дальше что? Вы его никуда не записали. Но зато в `validated` сырые данные, отчего Вы и получаете в базе пароль как есть.

Вариант "в лоб":

```
User::create($request->validated() + [
    'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
]);
```

---

Вариант (совсем немного) посложнее:

Модель `User`

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($value);
}
```

В контроллере без изменений

```
User::create($request->validated());
```

Comment: Решение второе рабочее, но заметил то, что теперь при обычной регистрации вне админ панели пароль хешируется, получается, два раза? В следствии чего новые зарегистрированные пользователи не могут войти, как это можно исправить? 
Я так понимаю, одно из решений - поменять `<input name="password">` в админ панели на другое значение, и саму функцию? 
Но как это грамотно сделать?

Comment: @Michael пароль должен сохраняться/меняться только тогда, когда он действительно изменяется. Если в админ панели в редактируете юзера, то вписывать пароль  надо только в том случае, если он действительно был изменен.

Comment: @teran всё верно, вопрос в другом. Когда я создаю нового пользователя в админ панели, то всё ок, я могу авторизоваться под ним. Но когда я регистрирую нового пользователя через регистрацию, и пытаюсь авторизоваться под ним, форма выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: @Michael Всё зависит от того, как сделана форма регистрации у Вас. Или нужно убрать хеширование внутри там, или использовать первый вариант везде. Второй вариант предполагает, что до попадания в базу поле будет хешироваться вне зависимости от того, что там изменялось до того, как оно обновится

Comment: @VladimirGonchar форма регистрации - `php artisan ui bootstrap --auth` т.е ничего самописного.
Хотел использовать первый вариант, но он почему-то так же добавляет сырые данные в базу